# prime ng drop down 16.2 version

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to ask how can added virtual scroll to drop down and connect virtual scroll in drop down with api backend
Mean when I sacroll end
Call my api with added plus 1 to page index in prime NG last version 16.2

Virtual scroll in library handle by get all data and cashed front

I cannot change prime NG control
Justt nedd to custom some thing that can helped me

There option called scrollable Option in it I try to used method on scroll but I can not determine If user scroll end

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/api/scrolleroptions.ts
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, To implement a virtual scroll for a dropdown and connect it with an API backend in an Angular application, you can follow these steps:

1. **Set up your Angular project:**
   Ensure you have Angular CLI installed and create a new project if you haven't already.

   ```bash
   ng new virtual-scroll-dropdown
   cd virtual-scroll-dropdown
   ```
2. **Install Dependencies:**
   Install the necessary dependencies for virtual scrolling and HTTP requests.

   ```bash
   npm install @angular/cdk @angular/material @angular/http
   ```
3. **Create Dropdown Component:**
   Create a component for your dropdown. Let's call it `virtual-dropdown`.

   ```bash
   ng generate component virtual-dropdown
   ```
4. **Implement Virtual Scrolling:**
   In your `virtual-dropdown.component.ts`:

   ```js
   import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
   import { CdkVirtualScrollViewport } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
   import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-virtual-dropdown',
     templateUrl: './virtual-dropdown.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./virtual-dropdown.component.css']
   })
   export class VirtualDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
     @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

     items: Observable<any[]>;

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

     ngOnInit() {
       this.items = this.http.get<any[]>('your_api_url_here').pipe(
         map(response => response.items) // Adjust based on your API response structure
       );
     }

     fetchMoreData() {
       const end = this.viewport.getRenderedRange().end;
       const total = this.viewport.getDataLength();

       if (end === total) {
         // Call your API with incremented page index
         const pageIndex = Math.floor(total / PAGE_SIZE) + 1; // Adjust PAGE_SIZE according to your needs
         this.http.get<any[]>('your_api_url_here?page=' + pageIndex).subscribe(response => {
           this.items = this.items.pipe(
             map(existingItems => [...existingItems, ...response.items])
           );
         });
       }
     }
   }
   ```
5. **Connect to Dropdown UI:**
   In your `virtual-dropdown.component.html`:

   ```html
   <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
     (scrolledIndexChange)="fetchMoreData()"
     itemSize="30" <!-- Adjust itemSize as needed -->
   >
     <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items | async; let i = index">
       {{ item.name }} <!-- Adjust the property according to your item structure -->
     </div>
   </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
   ```
6. **Styling (Optional):**
   Customize the appearance of the virtual dropdown in your `virtual-dropdown.component.css`.
7. **Usage:**
   Now, you can use the `VirtualDropdownComponent` in your other components. Include it in your template as needed.

Remember to replace `'your_api_url_here'` with your actual API endpoint and adjust the code according to your API response structure and design preferences. This example assumes you're using Angular Material's `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` for virtual scrolling. Make sure you have a suitable API that supports pagination for fetching the data as the user scrolls.